# How to use variables and sessions in my sql statement?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have been testing my sql statement, in different ways, but it's not working. I'm having trouble writing my variables and my session in the sql statement.

```
function onelike()
{
    $_SESSION['admin_id']
    $resultLikeCheck = "SELECT FROM tbladminXshouts WHERE postId = $row['id'] AND admin_id = $_SESSION['admin_id']"; 
    $results = mysql_query($resultLikeCheck) or die('');

    if(mysql_num_rows($results) == 0) 
    {
        echo ('

                 `<form action="" method="POST"> 
                       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
                       <input type = "submit" name="Gilla" value = "Gilla"/> 
                  </form>`

              ');
    }
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Try saving the Session variable in a local variable first... And please, please, please sanitize user input.

Comment: @Ryoku Thanks, do mean like this $localVariabel = $_SESSION['admin_id'];? Then I use $localVariabel in my sql statement instead of $_SESSION['admin_id']?

Answer (score 2):

```
$resultLikeCheck = "SELECT FROM tbladminXshouts WHERE postId = $row['id'] AND admin_id ='{$_SESSION['admin_id']}'";
```

use of "{}" to interpolate variables inside strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$adminID= $_SESSION['admin_id'];
$rowID= $row['id'];
onelike($adminID,$rowID);

    function onelike($adminID,$rowID)
    {


    $resultLikeCheck = "SELECT * FROM tbladminXshouts WHERE postId = '{$rowID}' AND admin_id = '{$adminID}'";

    $results = mysql_query($resultLikeCheck) or die('');
```

And I'd recommend using mysqli_  functions instead of mysql_

Edit:
I think your problem is you are not passing your variables into the function. Functions in PHP have their own local variables and can't access variables outside themselves unless you send them in.
And yes, @Sajjad Merchant is right, the best way to interpolate variables into strings for queries is withuse  of "{}"

Comment: Thanks, thats a realy realy nice way to do it, Im gonna try it.